# NVIDIA graphic card driver

Tags: graphic-drivers

I am familiar with Ubuntu 14.04 and once its installation is complete I can install the NVIDIA graphic card driver from the Software & Updates. But when I installed Elementary OS Freya and then tried to install the Nvidia driver I couldn't find it. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Because it is somewhat hidden in elementary OS (as it doesn't have it's own Software Center).

Go:

`Ubuntu Software Center -> Edit (at the top menubar) -> Software Sources -> Additional Drivers.`

I know it's a pretty weird place for a thing that is so important but I think we have to wait for Loki and automatic hardware detection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that is what I did and it says that there are no additional drivers. Have I done something wrong or the Nvidia driver doesn't exist?

Comment: Hm... then I am clueless. I have GeForce 460 and it always finds like 5 or 6 different drivers. You could try http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/08/ubuntu-nvidia-graphics-drivers-ppa-is-ready-for-action this but this is still fresh and might not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

- hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> for the application launcher
- type "driver"
- select the entry "Addditional Drivers"
- pick the driver you want

Comment: Try before posting your answer checking other answers. Under my answer OP said that he has done it but the utility is not finding any drivers.